# HTTP Requset names are not coming in listener

Tags: jmeter, listener, threadgroup, viewresult

When I am running threadgroup for 5 loops in jmeter, the HTTP Request name are not coming after the first loop in View Result tree.Please guide me.

[image: View Result Tree]

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be the case

[image]

Most probably your Regular Expression Extractor and/or subsequent request fails somewhere somehow so:

1. Check the variable generated by the Regular Expression Extractor using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/)
2. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for any suspicious entries